# Accessing request attribute in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, request

I have the following line of code in my Action:

```
request.setAttribute("ACCEPTED_MESSAGE", "Transaction Accepted");
```

In my JSP, I am testing if the request attribute "ACCEPTED_MESSAGE" is NULL:

```
<s:if test="#request.ACCEPTED_MESSAGE != null">
   <s:property value="#request.ACCEPTED_MESSAGE" escapeHtml="false" />
   <br />
</s:if>
```

This never evaluates to true, even though the last line of code in the action (above) sets the request attribute.  I step through the debugger, check the request variable to make sure that the attribute and its value are there (they are), and then when the JSP pulls up, it's like it doesn't see the request attribute.

If I change every instance of "request" to "session", the message shows.  The problem is that I don't need it in the session...I need it in the request.

Is my syntax wrong?  I've tried many different things, but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** Thanks to everyone who helped!  The syntax was fine.  The problem was in the Action configuration. I replaced the result type with "chain" instead of "redirectAction" and got the desired result.  Thanks to you guys, I spent less time looking at the syntax and more time looking at the Action configuration.  You ROCK!

Comment: How do you get `request`? Show your action configuration for that action.

Comment: Without more details it's impossible to know what's actually happening during your request flow, e.g., is the response a `redirectAction`, is it actually in the correct action method, and so on.

Comment: @AleksandrM In the action (which implements `ServletRequestAware`), I have this line:
`private HttpServletRequest request;`
           
I know this works because later in the action, I am able to do this:
        
`HttpSession session = request.getSession();`
        
And the session is seen.  Like I said above, storing the attribute and value in the session works.  The debugger shows that when I store the attribute and value in the request, they ARE in the request.  But the syntax I use above to reference the attribute and value in the request isn't being recognized.

Comment: @user2678745 The syntax seems fine. Post your action configuration.

Comment: @AleksandrM OK, sir, will do!

Comment: Usage of  `chain` result is discouraged. Use `redirectAction` but pass needed parameters along to the next action or put them into session. You can self answer your question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `chain` in the action configuration and got the desired results.  Thanks to everyone who chimed in!  :)